# How to synchronise DVD-RW spindle motors

Tags: dc-motor, motor-controller, synchronization

Just bought a small DC motor speed controller (two LM324, two IRFZ44N, rated at 250W max output, input in range 5-10 to 30V DC) and started wondering how to synchronise six DVD-RW spindle motors (Nidec L16210A/18C293A160, nothing came from a google search). They have 6-pin flat cable but don't know which one returns the signal for rpm. And that's the problem - which solution (rdy kit or diy) can equal or balance their rpms in ±1-2% range? Seems it offers PWM regulation with choosable direction of rotation by jumpers (RIGHT on/off, LEFT on/off), done by B100K voltage regulator and a 35V 330µF capacitor

Comment: I strongly believe the DVD motors are BLDC.

Comment: If your torque needs are low enough that you can run them open loop, you can actually just wire the two BLDC motors in parallel and sequence them like a sort of 3-wire stepper motor.  But for meaningful torque you'd need two closed loop position-sending BLDC drivers either seeking a setpoint RPM or somehow coordinated with each other.  In theory you can even get them rotationally locked.

Comment: … **in theory** … in practice, it's much much easier to use a rubber belt and fake the secondary spindle, given the small torque.

Comment: In fact that's my idea to NOT use belt synchronisation due to different levels of slipperiness at each belt pulley

Comment: But you want to allow 2% speed derivation? Belts get it near to zero.

Comment: A rubber band would do it

Comment: @Janka It's not near zero - after a two weeks of mediocre usage my belt based cnc router started to lower its precision - went from 0.008mm precision to almost 0.02mm. The reason was those high class belts - they stretched

Comment: And you compare this to 2% speed derivation … how?

Comment: 2.5 times difference ... and you are asking how? Can you think what can happen if this occurs in the model I'm building? At least huge power consumption inefficiency